# md-datepicker + reactive forms + firebase + angular 4

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I have:
carico.model.ts

```
export class Carico {
  $key: string;
  dataCarico:  Date;
  riferimentoCarico: string;
  dettaglio:{
    carburante: string;
    quantita: string;
  }  
}
```

in my service:
carichi.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
....some code...    
import { Carico } from './carico.model';

@Injectable()
export class CarichiService {
  ...some code...    

  getCarichiList(query = {}): FirebaseListObservable<Carico[]> {
    if (!this.userId) return;
    this.carichi = this.db.list(`carico/${this.userId}`, { query: query }
    );
    return this.carichi
  }    
  ...some code...

  createCarico(carico: Carico): void {
    this.carichi.push(carico)
      .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
  }    
}
```

in my form component:
new-carico-form.component.ts

```
import { Carburante } from '../../impostazioni/carburanti/carburante.model';
import { CarburantiService } from '../../impostazioni/carburanti/carburanti.service';
...some code...

constructor(...) {    
    this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.carburanti = this.carburantiService.getCarburantiList();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.caricoForm = this.fb.group({
      dataCarico: Date,
      riferimentoCarico: [''],
      dettaglio: this.fb.group({        
        carburante: '',
        quantita: ''
      })
    });
  }

 inserisciCarico(carico: Carico) {
    this.carichiService.getCarichiList();       
    this.carichiService.createCarico(this.caricoForm.value);    
    this.caricoForm.reset();
  }

  onSubmit() {
  }

}
```

and my html:
new-carico-form-component.html

```
<md-card>  
    <form [formGroup]="caricoForm" novalidate>
      <md-card-content>
        <md-input-container >
          <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="seleziona data" formControlName="dataCarico">
          <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker" ></button>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
        <span class="col"> </span>
        <md-input-container>
          <input mdInput placeholder="riferimento" formControlName="riferimentoCarico">
        </md-input-container>
        <table formGroupName="dettaglio">          
          <tr>
            <td>
              <md-select placeholder="carburante" formControlName="carburante">                    
...some code...
```

The problem is that I can save the form the only thing that does not work is the date. I tried to show in the console before and after the subscription and the date is in the form. any suggestions? I go in Firebase back and there is everything except the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will **not** be able to push a `Date` object to the firebase database. You'd need to transform the `Date` to milliseconds or a string using something like [Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) or [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

```
inserisciCarico(carico: Carico) {
   this.carichiService.getCarichiList();
   let formValue = this.caricoForm.value;
   formValue.dataCarico = formValue.dataCarico.getTime();
   // or
   // formValue.dataCarico = formValue.dataCarico.getISOString(); 

   this.carichiService.createCarico(formValue );    
   this.caricoForm.reset();
}
```

If you check the type of the `dateCarico` using `Object.prototype.toString.call(carico.dateCarico)` you'll see it's a `[object Date]` from the `mdDatepicker`, this needs to be converted to milliseconds or string to be able to go to the firebase database.

You will likely need to modify `Carico` class to accept either a Date or string:

```
dataCarico:  Date | string;
```

Hope that helps!